# Automatically generated field in model

Tags: python

**My model:**

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    UserFirstName = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[name_regex])
    UserMiddleName = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[name_regex])
    UserLastName = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[name_regex])
    UserFullName = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[name_regex])
```

**My Serializer:**

```
class UserInfoNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ('UserFirstName', 'UserMiddleName', 'UserLastName', 'UserFullName')
        read_only_fields = ['UserFullName']
```

**I want fields UserFullName created from User UserFirstName, UserMiddleName and UserLastName.**

**I tried but fail**

```
@property
    def UserFullName(self):
        return self.UserFirstName + " " + self.UserMiddleName + " " + self.UserLastName
```

**Help me, please!!**

Comment: You should use `def __str__(self): return self.UserFirstName+" " + self.UserMiddleName + " " + self.UserLastName`

Comment: Field UserFullName: Do you need to declare anything?

Comment: Models like this, right?

class UserInfo(models.Model):
    UserFirstName = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[name_regex])
    UserMiddleName = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[name_regex])
    UserLastName = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[name_regex])
    UserFullName = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[name_regex])

    def __str__(self): return self.UserFirstName+" " + self.UserMiddleName + " " + self.UserLastName